# Displaying a Grid Through a Function Using For Loops

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently working on an assignment and am currently stuck. The program has the function `function createGrid()`. This function is supposed to create a grid with the variable `letters` based on what the user inputs for `rows` and `columns` in the input boxes on the form . `letters` is the entire alphabet in all caps.  `function createGrid()` doesn't output anything and I have no syntax errors. The output of `function createGrid()` looks like the example below. The only function that works is `function resetForm()`.Does anyone know where I went wrong?

**Example how the function is supposed to work and what the output is supposed to look like:** User entered 3 for rows and 30 for columns

```
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z A B C D 
Z A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z A B C 
Y Z A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z A B
```

**My Code Currently**

```
<script>

function createGrid(){
            
            let script = "";
            let rows = document.getElementsByName("rows").value;
            let columns =  document.getElementsByName("columns").value;
            let letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    
            // outer for loop to display rows    
            for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++){
                script += letters.charAt(i);
    
               // inner for loop to display columns 
                for (let j =0; j < columns; j++){
                let k = (i * rows + j)% 26;
                script += letters.charAt(k);
             }   
             script += "<br>";
            }
            
            
            //creates grid and displays in the <pre> tag
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = script;
        }

function resetForm(){

            document.getElementsByName("myForm")[0].reset();
            rows = document.getElementsByName("rows").value; ;
            second = document.getElementsByName("columns").value;
            }
    </script>
```

```
<body>
    <h1>Letter Grid</h1>

    <form name="myForm">

        Number of Rows
        <!--prompts user to input number of rows -->
        <input type="number" name="rows" value="">
        Number of Columns
        <!--allows user to input number of columns-->
        <input type = "number" name="columns" value="" >
        <!--submit button to initiate function using users input-->
        <input type="button" value="Submit Values"  onclick="javascript:createGrid()">
        <!--resets the form so user can insert different numbers-->
          <input type="button" onclick="resetForm();" value="Reset the form" >

        <pre id="results"></pre>

    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: When trying to debug something, *do the simplest thing you can think of*. You've got a form, and some buttons, two functions, etc. spread across Javascript and HTML. Strip it down to a single function, a single div, and see if you can generate output (or even just output to the JS console at first). *Then* add the moving parts, *slowly*, one at a time. If you just try to wire up a bunch of code without running it you won't have any idea what's going wrong.

Comment: thank you for the tip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementsByName` returns an array of elements not a singular element.

As such you simply need to change it to `document.getElementsByName("rows")[0].value` and the same for columns.

Alternatively your could use `querySelector` which returns a singular item by targeting the `name` attribute using `document.querySelector('input[name="rows"]').value;`.

I have included both in the following example.

### Corrected fiddle

```js
function createGrid(){
            
            let script = "";
            let rows = document.querySelector('input[name="rows"]').value; //changed this line to demonstrate querySelector
            let columns =  document.getElementsByName("columns")[0].value; //also changed this line to show how to select the first item in the array
            let letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    
            // outer for loop to display rows    
            for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++){
                script += letters.charAt(i);
    
               // inner for loop to display columns 
                for (let j =0; j < columns; j++){
                let k = (i * rows + j)% 26;
                script += letters.charAt(k);
             }   
             script += "<br>";
            }
            
            
            //creates grid and displays in the <pre> tag
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = script;
        }

function resetForm(){

            document.getElementsByName("myForm")[0].reset();
            rows = document.getElementsByName("rows").value; ;
            second = document.getElementsByName("columns").value;
            }
```

```html
<body>
    <h1>Letter Grid</h1>

    <form name="myForm">

        Number of Rows
        <!--prompts user to input number of rows -->
        <input type="number" name="rows" value="">
        Number of Columns
        <!--allows user to input number of columns-->
        <input type = "number" name="columns" value="" >
        <!--submit button to initiate function using users input-->
        <input type="button" value="Submit Values"  onclick="javascript:createGrid()">
        <!--resets the form so user can insert different numbers-->
          <input type="button" onclick="resetForm();" value="Reset the form" >

        <pre id="results"></pre>

    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Ahhh ok I orignally had that but changed them all to ````document.getElementsByName````. Quick question do you know why the output always displays two AAs at the beginning of grid ? Its the only time two AAs are displayed. The rest of the grid goes ABC... and so on

Comment: yeah `script += letters.charAt(i);` outputs "A" and then in the loop `let k = (i * rows + j)% 26;` is also going to output "A" as `i` is 0 and `j` is 0.

Comment: oh ok. I understand now. How would I correct the double from occurring? should I change ````j```` to 1?

Comment: That is more fun for you to try and work out, but I will give you a clue, at the moment you actually output an extra character per row due to the same issue.

Comment: step through each step in each loop on paper and you will soon see it. i.e. write each character as it would occur in each loop and you will soon see your mistake.

Comment: thanks for the practice run. I see what I was doing wrong. I added the ````script+=```` twice when it really only needed to be in the inner ````for```` loop

Comment: Yes exactly! Glad you worked it out, far better way to learn than to have someone show you all the answers. Good luck with the rest of the assignment.